# Как задать право на просмотр файлов заданной папки всем пользователям?

Tags: asp.net

Вот такой вот файл мне попался на хостинге, надо дать доступ к папке 'uploads/images/'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCG1" path="*.htm" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP54\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCG2" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP54\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <ModSecurity enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

я к .net вообще не прикасался даже, погуглил, несколько раз пытался добавить

```
<location path="uploads/images">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

в разные места конфига - всегда вылазила ошибка 500.

Comment: Открыть Event Log и посмотреть почему ошибка 500. Скорее всего, ошибка в том как написан config -- в структуре тэгов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно основной web.config вернуть к состоянию "как было", и прямо в папку uploads/images положить отдельный небольшой web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```